# Conditional Formatting Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am trying to work with an excel file and use conditional formatting. i have posted a screenshot below of what i am working with. When the priority column has an input of "Yes" and the Task completed column has an input of "No" i would like that task completed box that says "no" to turn yellow. How do i do this. I have been trying for quite some time and standard google searches have not worked! Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I started with the data shown above. In order to have it set up to turn yellow do the following:

1. Select the cell that you wish to apply the rule to.
2. Select Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules.. > More Rules
3. Select Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4. For my example above I would use this formula:

   ```
   =IF($A$1="Yes",IF($B$1="No",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
   ```

   Whatever formula you do use, whenever the results are true, this highlight rule is applied.
5. Click Format.. and chose a color under the fill tab. This color will fill the back color when the formula you entered in 4) is true.
6. Click Ok, OK, OK and you should be good to go.

Comment: Question: What if i want it to turn yellow when it says "No" and "N/A" but not when it says "Yes", how do i add a third piece to the formula. Please and thank you!!

Comment: @jcollins - did you read the formula? It's really not that difficult to manipulate. Have a go first and see if you can do it yourself.

Comment: Exactly like Paul said. Take a look at the formula I gave you, learn how it works, try something, and let me know where you got stuck and what you tried. Everything is identical except step 4, if you change how many